# semantic-release pre error locally and with Jenkins CI server

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, semantic-release

I am trying to setup semantic-release with Jenkins, and I stepped through the documentation, eggheadio, Github Issues, and of course Google. I am stuck and need some kind help.

**.npmrc**

```
registry=https://nexus.<org>.com/repository/npm_registry/
email=<email>
always-auth=true
_auth=<auth>
//nexus.<org>.com/repository/npm_registry/:_authToken=<token>
```

I don't think anything in my `.npmrc` is wrong. I can publish to my Nexus artifact repository just fine.

This is in my package.json
`"semantic-release":"semantic-release pre && npm publish && semantic-release post"` and semantic cli setup default my version to `"version": "0.0.0-development"`

Where I am receiving errors, is when I run `semantic-release pre`. This command is not working on both my dev machine and Jenkins CI Server. I get this error when trying to release on my Jenkins Server...

```
semantic-release WARN pre semantic-release didn’t run on Travis CI and therefore a new version won’t be published.
semantic-release WARN pre You can customize this behavior using "verifyConditions" plugins: git.io/sr-plugins
semantic-release ERR! commits The commit the last release of this package was derived from is not in the direct history of the "master" branch.
semantic-release ERR! commits This means semantic-release can not extract the commits between now and then.
semantic-release ERR! commits This is usually caused by force pushing, releasing from an unrelated branch, or using an already existing package name.
semantic-release ERR! commits You can recover from this error by publishing manually or restoring the commit "f92012978d1c5f48c3f88d2150bf9c9cfba9c04e".
semantic-release ERR! commits Here is a list of branches that still contain the commit in question: 
semantic-release ERR! commits  * * (HEAD detached at a09cd81)
semantic-release ERR! pre Failed to determine new version.
semantic-release ERR! pre ENOTINHISTORY Commit not in history
```

If you are curious about the error I am receiving on my dev machine:

```
semantic-release WARN pre semantic-release didn’t run on Travis CI and therefore a new version won’t be published.
semantic-release WARN pre You can customize this behavior using "verifyConditions" plugins: git.io/sr-plugins
semantic-release ERR! pre Failed to determine new version.
semantic-release ERR! pre ENOCHANGE There are no relevant changes, so no new version is released.
```

I hope this is enough information, but please ask if you need more!

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message suggests about `verifyConditions`?

Comment: Sure enough that worked! Thanks for spotting that for me (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [condition-jenkins](https://github.com/krux/condition-jenkins) if you are experiencing similar issue. (: